# shell echo not appearing in cygwin?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script where I'm setting some variables, but I'd like to echo them to be certain they're correct. However I'm getting a blank line. Does anyone know why this happens because the syntax seems correct.

```
#!/bin/bash
set var='test'
echo $var
```

Since I'm on a windows machine I'm using cygwin to test my script.

Comment: When you `set var='test'`, you are setting positional parameter 1 to the value `var='test'`. This would output what you expect to see: `echo $1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
var='test'
echo $var
```

set can be used to set shell attributes, not variables.

Comment: Note that this is the same with bash on Linux or FreeBSD or OpenSolaris... I'm deleting the cygwin tag

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this issue on machines where I tried to upgrade cygwin. If you upgraded cygwin or installed additional components try reinstalling cygwin.

Comment: I downloaded it today and did a default install.